# Web Scraping with Beautifulsoup and returning a json dump from individual dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a number of HTML files in my Pc that I need to scrape some data from them that are nested in tables and then create from the info scrapped from the different tables a unified json.dump I have managed to scrape the tables for the and created a dictionary that holds a list with the info from each table and then I am placing the information I want to a second dictionary  using the following approach which is basically repeated 3 times inside a function

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup((open(r'C:\file1.htm')),"html.parser")

table = soup.find_all('table')[9]
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:9]
data =  {'first_page':[]}
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    str(data['first_page'].append( cols[0].get_text()))
    str(data['first_page'].append( cols[1].get_text()))



data.get("first_page")[0]
(data.get("first_page")[1]).strip('\n')
data.get("first_page")[6]
(data.get("first_page")[7]).strip('\n')
data.get("first_page")[12]
(data.get("first_page")[13]).strip('\n')
dictionary={}
dictionary[data.get("first_page")[0]]=(data.get("first_page")[1]).strip('\n')
dictionary[data.get("first_page")[6]]=(data.get("first_page")[7]).strip('\n')
dictionary[data.get("first_page")[12]]=(data.get("first_page")[13]).strip('\n')
```

Two problems I am facing:

1. How do I unify the 3 individual dictionaries that contain the
   final data I want? note that the final json.dump must have a
   specific order in terms of the elements that they are contained in
   it
2. Part of the data from the tables are percentages for example
   '\n'-0,58%'\n' when I scrape them I have managed to remove the
   "white noise" with .strip but it seems that after I cannot convert
   them to numbers any ideas?

Comment: 2:`float("'\n'-0,58%'\n'".strip("'\n'").replace(',','.').strip('%'))`

Comment: Thanks for the tip I noticed that I have given two arguments for the strip function I was using that's why i got the error